# why the browser can not read the ID in Java with BDD eclipse however in other website is reading it with the same code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, cucumber-junit

I have java code for one of my automation website and I copy that code to other PC to run other Website however the first step is running ok which is open the URL but the rest can not be run , unable to locate the element id , here is the code in Java:

```
@When("^I enter (.*) in the (.*)$")
public void i_enter_in_the_Username_txt_box(String emailaddress,String boxname) throws Throwable {
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,LOAD); 
  By id = By.id(boxname);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(id));
driver.findElement(By.id(boxname)).sendKeys(emailaddress); 
}
```

BDD for this code is :

```
Feature: XYZ

Scenario: Add valid username and password then click on login button

Given User at login page // this one is working fine 
When I enter Admin in the username // this one is not working , error saying that the Id for the username field can not find 
And  I enter Admin in the password
Then Home page will display
```

Would you please let me now if you know where is the issue ? 
I tried the following but still i got the error :

1. Add Thread.sleep(1000); to wait but still i got the error
2. I added "" for the Admin and the Id for the field in the BDD file but still it did not work

I am using cucumber , Firefox , selenium , Eclipse , BDD, Maven and Java
Thanks a lot

Comment: you need to run your code in debug mode to understand which element is not able to locate

Answer (score 0):

Try change this `driver.findElement(By.id(boxname)).sendKeys(emailaddress);` to `driver.findElement(id).sendKeys(emailaddress);`

Comment: there's no difference in that..either we use By.id or use object of it

Comment: id is correct as OP says its running on one machine

Comment: I suspect it could maybe just have something to do with Firefox version. Can you please try switching the browser flavor to chrome (or) IE and see if that works ? [ Unlike chrome and IE which are driven by external binaries, firefox has a tight coupling on the Selenium version that it works with ]. Also please help share the exact exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I found couple of issue. I am not clear what error you are getting that's reason I am trying to debug multiple way.

```
Feature: XYZ

Scenario: Add valid username and password then click on login button

Given User at login page // this one is working fine 
When I enter Admin in the username // this one is not working , error saying that the Id for the username field can not find 
And  I enter Admin in the password
Then Home page will display
```

This is not correct. Given statement will work because you are not passing any value as parameters from statement to step definition.

It is failing here `When I enter Admin in the username`

because you didn't add parameter well.

I think you can do this way

```
When I enter "stack@stack.com" in the "username"
```

Currently It will take two user parameters as per your step definition requirement.

*I am expecting "username" is your box name.*

**other reason could :**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,LOAD);
```

Are you sure you are getting driver and LOAD in step definition ?